# Clustering near Lines using coordinates in Python

Tags: python, list, line, cluster-analysis, distance

I have a list with x- and y-coordinates of start and Endpoints of some lines.[Lines as csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSm3m.png)

```
331,178,486,232
185,215,386,308
172,343,334,419
406,128,570,165
306,106,569,166
159,210,379,299
236,143,526,248
303,83,516,178
409,62,572,106
26,287,372,427
31,288,271,381
193,228,432,330
120,196,432,329
136,200,374,297
111,189,336,289
284,186,560,249
333,202,577,254
229,194,522,219
349,111,553,165
121,322,342,416
78,303,285,391
103,315,340,415
```

The lines look like this on my example image. [Lines plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmpH8.jpg)
I want to group lines which are close to each other into clusters and create one line for each cluster. For this example i would like to have 5 clusters. After that i want to calculate the distance from each clusterline to the next.

```
import csv, math
file = open("lines.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

lines = []
for data in csvreader:
    lines.append({'x1':int(data[0]), 'y1':int(data[1]), 'x2':int(data[2]), 'y2':int(data[3])})

def point_delta(p1, p2):
    return abs(p1 - p2)


for line in lines[:2]:    
    for line_rev in lines:        
        #x_start_delta = abs(line['x1'] - line_rev['x1'])
        x_start_delta = point_delta(line['x1'], line_rev['x1'])
        y_start_delta = abs(line['y1'] - line_rev['y1'])
        start_distance = math.sqrt(x_start_delta**2 + y_start_delta**2)
        x_end_delta = abs(line['x2'] - line_rev['x2'])
        y_end_delta = abs(line['y2'] - line_rev['y2'])
        end_distance = math.sqrt(x_end_delta**2 + y_end_delta**2)
        avg_distance = (start_distance + end_distance)/2
        cluster = 0
        if avg_distance < 100: 
            print(f"distance: {avg_distance}")
            
    print("############## next line ##############")
```

I have written some code to calculate the distance between each line but cant find a way to save the lines which are near to each other in different lists.

Does somebody know how to do this or is there another way to create clusters? Im also thinking about using the middlepoint instead of the start-/endpoint

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a clustering on it, but it has trouble with the lonely line at the end

[image: lines]

---

```
data = [[331,178,486,232],
[185,215,386,308],
[172,343,334,419],
[406,128,570,165],
[306,106,569,166],
[159,210,379,299],
[236,143,526,248],
[303,83,516,178],
[409,62,572,106],
[26,287,372,427],
[31,288,271,381],
[193,228,432,330],
[120,196,432,329],
[136,200,374,297],
[111,189,336,289],
[284,186,560,249],
[333,202,577,254],
[229,194,522,219],
[349,111,553,165],
[121,322,342,416],
[78,303,285,391],
[103,315,340,415]]

import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
import numpy as np

lines = pd.DataFrame(data)

CLUSTERS = 5

X = lines.values

kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=CLUSTERS,max_no_improvement=100).fit(X)

import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

lines_segments = [ [ (l[0],l[1]),([l[2],l[3]]) ] for l in lines.values]
center_segments = [ [ (l[0],l[1]),([l[2],l[3]]) ] for l in kmeans.cluster_centers_] 


line_collection = mc.LineCollection(lines_segments, linewidths=2)
centers = mc.LineCollection(center_segments, colors='red', linewidths=4, alpha=1)

fig, ax = pl.subplots()

ax.add_collection(line_collection)
ax.add_collection(centers)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
```

You can see the centers with

```
kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also tried out kmeans clustering, but i want my code to decide how many clusters there are. Linesclustering doesnt seem to work well so i switched to clustering the middle points of each line.
I found this thread https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224704/grouping-sorted-coordinates-based-on-proximity-to-each-other   which helped me alot. With a little bit of additional code i can now get all line-middlepoints clustered correctly.